# How to indicate that a word / acronym X will refer to Y in academic writing

Tags: single-word-requests

How would I indicate, for example, that I am going to use "toms" to mean "tomatoes". Something like:

> Tomatoes (toms) are red. This is false as some toms are green. I like toms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have often seen it in brackets, as in your example, with quotation marks and a capital:

> Tomatoes **("Toms")** are red. This is false, as some Toms are green. I like Toms.

I suppose the capital is not always necessary if the thing referred to isn't a name or a proper noun; however, it is easier to spot that this thing is special later if you use a capital throughout.

In legal texts, they use **hereafter** or **hereinafter**:

> Tomatoes, **hereafter called "Toms",** are red. This is false, as some Toms are green. I like Toms.

But this is not recommended in academic writing. You could simply use **in this paper** and explain what you're going to do:

> Tomatoes, **which will be referred to as "Toms" in this paper,** are red. This is false, as some Toms are green. I like Toms.
>
> Tomatoes, **which we will refer to as "Toms" in this paper,** are red. This is false, as some Toms are green. I like Toms.

Comment: What about "Tomatoes (hereinafter referred to as 'Toms') are red."?

Comment: @ErikHumphrey: Sounds good to me! The only thing is that the word *herinafter* is widely considered very formal outside legal text; I don't think I've ever seen it in an academic article.

Comment: @ErikHumphrey, I use `hereafter "Toms"`

Comment: @Cerberus, Re "not recommended.."; Why not?

Comment: @Pacerier: Well, I would say it is a bit too formal for (non-legal) academic writing? Maybe I can be proved wrong here.

Comment: @Cerberus, The shorter form is always potentially better.